# My program is working correctly, but I get a warning

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have allocated memory for a double pointer and I have populated it with some values. (1) After that, I created a function that populates the ints with 0. Then I have made a pointer to that function and created another function that uses that pointer as an argument.

I ran the program and it was working, but the problem was that I was getting a warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'cheama_transforma0' makes pointer from integer without a cast

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printeaza_pointer(int **cacat){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d\n",cacat[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
int transforma_in0(int **cacat){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cacat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void cheama_transforma0(int (*p)(int **pointer)){

}
int main()
{
    int (*p)(int **cacat);
    int **pointer_d = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pointer_d[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            pointer_d[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    p = transforma_in0;
    printeaza_pointer(pointer_d);
    cheama_transforma0(p(pointer_d));
    printeaza_pointer(pointer_d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"... and crated another function that uses that pointer as an argument."* - that's not what you're passing as an argument. The formal argument for `cheama_transforma0` is `int (*p)(int **pointer)`. You're passing the *result* of *invoking* the function pointer `p` via `p(pointer_d)`. That function invoke returns `int`, not `int (*p)(int **pointer)`, so the compiler is correct to complain.

Comment: It's just a good thing `chaema_transforma0` doesn't try to do anything at all with `p`, since it does not in fact point at a function.

Answer (score 2):

> "passing argument 1 of 'cheama_transforma0' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

```
void cheama_transforma0(int (*p)(int **pointer));
int **pointer_d;
int (*p)(int **cacat);
cheama_transforma0(p(pointer_d));
```

The `p` is a function pointer to a function that returns an `int`. If you pass the return value from the `p` function as the first argument to `cheama_transforma0` function, the compiler will cast the `int` value returned by the `p` function to an `int (*)(int **pointer)` function pointer type. Thus the warning.

Comment: so...what do you recommend?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to do. What is `cheama_transforma0` function supposed to do? (I advise to name all symbols in english, so others can simply understand you). There is no function body, so I don't know what the function should do?

Comment: suppose to manifest the function transforma_in0 using a pointer

Comment: [manifest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manifest) ? You mean _call_ ? With what parameters. I think what you mean is `int cheama_transforma0(int (*func)(int **pointer), int **data){
   return func(data);
}` and to call `cheama_transforma0(p, pointer_d)`.

Comment: i wanted to make a function that calls another function and modifies the array

Comment: yesssss...thx man... now it is working ...thank you very much